# Devuelve Null con List<T> de objetos - Web API Post

Tags: c#, json, rest

Estoy tratando de pasar una Lista a mi API web pero sigo obteniendo un valor nulo.  debo convertir la lista en una json antes de pasarla al método, consultaPuertos?.

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultaPuertos([FromUri] string id, 
    [FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
  {

     //aca debo hacer algo para que no llegue el list<> en null
         var resultList1 = puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, 
    fecha);
 return Task.FromResult(resultList1);
  });
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo puedo vincularlo correctamente?

---

**UPDATE** Los datos los envio en postman por uri y por Body con RAW JSON:

```
{
 "lstPuertosGP": 
   [   
     {
       "ObjID":"Frt00001",
       "Clase":"0.5 S"
     },
     {
       "ObjID":"Frt00002",
       "Clase":"0.2 S"
     } 
  ]
}
```

la fecha y id los envio por uri

```
[Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/{id}/{fecha}")]
```

Comment: Saludos, ¿podrías agregar cómo le envías los datos y qué pasos realizas para dicho fin, por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes mal construido el Json que envías en el **`Body`** con RAW JSON, lo correcto debería ser así:

```
[   
  {
    "ObjID":"Frt00001",
    "Clase":"0.5 S"
  },
  {
    "ObjID":"Frt00002",
    "Clase":"0.2 S"
  } 
]
```

---

**Importante:** Debes tener en cuenta que debes enviar el `List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP` en el cuerpo (**Body**), y `string id` y `DateTime fecha` en la **Url**, **`/api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/12323/2019-11-19`**

Comment: Esa era la respuesta!!! los id y fecha si los envio  por la url, ahora ya solo saca error 
{
    "Message": "El recurso solicitado no admite el método http 'POST'."
}

Comment: ¿En qué se diferencia esta respuesta con la que hice?

Comment: @fredyfx: El error estaba en el Json, **no le sobraba una coma**, simplemente estaba mal *parseado*. Tu respuesta es de utilidad, pero no soluciona la pregunta. El "preguntante" quería saber porqué le llegaba null al Controlador en el parámetro `List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP`.

Comment: gracias por el dato mi estimado :D

Comment: @fredyfx: De nada a ti, eres uno de los grandes por aquí.;).

Comment: Gracias hermano, un gusto ver que el clan de "DotNeteros" sigue creciendo :D

Answer (score 0):

**Actualización**

> Estoy tratando de pasar una Lista a mi API web pero sigo obteniendo un valor nulo.

La siguiente respuesta contiene un ejemplo basado en el código de la pregunta, donde sí se obtienen los valores enviados a la url generada en:

```
[Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/{id}/{fecha}")]
```

**Veamos:**

Hay varias cosas a tener en cuenta, primero el JSON que estás enviando está mal hecho, está sobrando una coma:

```
{
 "lstPuertosGP": 
   [   
     {
       "ObjID":"Frt00001",
       "Clase":"0.5 S"
     },
     {
       "ObjID":"Frt00002",
       "Clase":"0.2 S"
     } 
  ], //Esta coma está sobrando
}
```

En el archivo `RouteConfig.cs` necesitas agregar:

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "wasd",
            url: "api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/{id}/{fecha}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "ConsultaPuertos", id = UrlParameter.Optional, fecha = UrlParameter.Optional }

        );
```

Y en tu controlador:

```
    [System.Web.Http.Route("api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/{id}/{fecha}")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    public async Task<IList<PuertosGP>> ConsultaPuertos([FromUri] string id, [FromBody] List<PuertosGP> lstPuertosGP, [FromUri] DateTime fecha)
    {
        PuertosGP puertosGPRepository = new PuertosGP();
        //aca debo hacer algo para que no llegue el list<> en null
        var resultList1 = new List<PuertosGP>() {
            new PuertosGP() { Clase="WASD", ObjID="123qwe" }
        };

        return await Task.FromResult(resultList1);
    }
```

El ejemplo que utilicé fue esta URL:

```
http://localhost:55698/api/ConsultasGP/ConsultasPuertos/1/2019-11-18
```

Le envié el JSON mostrado al inicio de esta respuesta, sin la coma extra y funcionó correctamente.

El Modelo usado fue:

```
public class PuertosGP
{
    public string ObjID { get; set; }
    public string Clase { get; set; }
}
```

Si te sigue dando null, vas a tener que revisar tu método:

```
puertosGPRepository.ConsultaPuertos(id, lstPuertosGP, fecha);
```

Y verificar que tienes datos que cumplen los parámetros enviados, porque me late que nada cumple y por ende, null.

Comment: no necesito crear un list dentro de el metodo  var resultList1 = new List<PuertosGP>() {
            new PuertosGP() { Clase="WASD", ObjID="123qwe" }
        }; necesito leerlo u obtenerlo y retornar otro list

Comment: Es un ejemplo. No tengo idea de qué tienes en tu repositorio, pues no hay código del mismo en tu pregunta. Al final de la respuesta ofrecida expliqué el motivo de esa línea. Saludos :D